# _Generic and functions with several parameters

Tags: c, generic-programming, c11

I was reading this C11's `_Generic` example on Wikipedia:

```
#define cbrt(X) _Generic((X), long double: cbrtl, \
                          default: cbrt, \
                          float: cbrtf)(X)
```

It seems pretty clear how to use it for functions with only one parameter, but I can't see a way to write functions with two (or more) generic parameters with this system. How could it be possible?

I would have tried some things if some compiler supported this feature but I could not find one either, so I was unable to find any idea on how to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously there is no "generic" rule for this, it really depends on the use case. But one typical use case would be to use the standard promotions to determine a common "supertype"

```
#define pow(X, Y) _Generic((X)+(Y), long double: powl, \
                          default: pow,                \
                          float: powf)((X), (Y))
```

If `X` and `Y` wouldn't agree in type when calling this macro, the narrow one would automatically be promoted to the wider one.

Comment: Hum, that's pretty smart. Is this how `<tgmath.h>` functions should now be implemented?

Comment: I think that is one of the ideas, to have means inside the language to implement tgmath.h. And since `_Generic` isn't optional, even if there isn't `tgmath.h` you'd know how to implement it :)